# Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: $

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two sites that are identical, one working, the other not quite which is getting a javascript error.

The primary functions are where the user clicks the SAVE NOW button, and the file.js will validate the Save Now function and allow the user to Continue to the shopping cart, the Continue button is behind the "Design Not Saved Button".  The shopping cart is on a Hidden Panel above the editor and the Continue button UnHides the Hidden Panel named "cart".  On this cart panel there is a paypal form with a script prices.js.

This works fine in the first link, but in the second link listed below, the Throbber Image just spins and will not validate the save function, thus allowing the user to Never continue to the shopping cart.

I am assuming that you can easily find the file.js and popular_prices.js by visiting the above links.

I am not the greatest coder (self-taught and dangerous) and am very stumped on this, can anyone suggest how to fix this, and explain it in simple terms that I might be able to understand?

**Thank you in advance!**

Working link:
http://www.budgetsignstore.com/popular-sign-designer.html?320-1c-automotive-magnet-banner-template-green-auto-south-detail

Non-working Link:
http://www.lowcostsigns.com/banner-editor.html?320-1c-automotive-magnet-banner-template-green-auto-south-detail

Here is the error I am getting:

```
[1/26/2014 11:07:31 AM] JavaScript - http://www.lowcostsigns.com/low-cost-signs-online-editor.html?320-1c-automotive-magnet-banner-template-green-auto-south-detail
Inline script thread
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: $
Error thrown at line 3, column 0 in http://www.lowcostsigns.com/file.js:
    $(document).ready(function () {
[1/26/2014 11:07:31 AM] JavaScript - http://www.lowcostsigns.com/low-cost-signs-online-editor.html?320-1c-automotive-magnet-banner-template-green-auto-south-detail
Inline script thread
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: $
Error thrown at line 467, column 0 in http://www.lowcostsigns.com/popular_prices.js:
    $(document).ready(function () {
```

Comment: You probably didn't load jQuery library, and therefore $, which stands for jQuery object, is not defined.

Comment: Please have a look at this Meta discussion [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/142802).

Comment: Thank you Pavel S. very helpful for my understanding.

Comment: Thank you Felix, this helps me understand more how to use this service better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line 118: `<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jquery.js"></script>`

Try moving it above line 24: `<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jsNavBarFuncs.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me with this! Moving the jquery from line 118 to line 24 was perfect!  Now I understand just a little bit more than before and should be able to resolve this in the future.  The wsiwyg program placed the code in an odd place, so this answers much!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

as i see in the code you are loading that files before you load jquery. please, 
move your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wpscripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

to the top of the header